# How can I use Persian date (Shamsi)?

Tags: excel, calendar, excel-2007, farsi

I'd like to use Persian date (Hijri- Shamsi) in Excel 2007 worksheet directly as the base of calculation. How is that possible?

Comment: Since this has nothing at all to do with either programming or programming logic it is not a question for StackOverflow. It is a good fit for SuperUser, though, so I'm voting to move it there.

Comment: as Gary says I guess the only way is use VBA. BTW what calculation do you need?

Answer (score 2):

I would convert the Persian dates to Julian dates via **VBA** , perform the calculations with standard Excel functions and then convert them back to Persian with **VBA**

I posted a reference [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/how-to-use-persian-dates-in-excel/c8a874fc-e764-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)

Comment: I visited that page and codes but unfortunately did not understand at all cuz, im not familiar with VBA. Do you mind if i send you an example and receive back the modified just to see how the job has been done?