# Using Excel DateAdd Function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use excel DateAdd function to add some days to a cell containing a persian/hijri calendar date. So, I've created a button and assigned a macro to it like :

```
Sub mydateaddfunction()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim Number As Integer
      FirstDate = Sheets(3).Range("e13").Value
      Number = Sheets(3).Range("b13").Value
      Sheets(3).Range("e14").Value = DateAdd("d", Number, FirstDate)
End Sub
```

but unfortunately it throws an error

> application defined or object-defined error

error coming from this line :

```
Sheets(3).Range("e14").Value = DateAdd("d", Number, FirstDate)
```

e13 cell contains the date, b13 contains the number of days I want to add to the e13 cell. so if e13 cell be something like :

> 1396/10/17

and b13 contains a number like 3, I want e14 to be:

> 1396/10/20

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880225/how-can-i-use-persian-date-shamsi-in-excel-2007

Comment: In case of Office 365 you might already have this https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.uservoice.com/assets/112/838/348/original/Persian_Calendar.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF4UXUF6KJMEJFQQ&Expires=1514368061&Signature=zVpAu5nPVupoebvPXJJD1cefWrs%3D

Comment: Very likely, either E13 isn't a date and/or B13 isn't a number. In both cases, test with this formula, `=VALUE(E13)`, respectively B13. In both cases the formula will return a #VALUE error if the cell contains a string. The equivalent in VBA is the Val() function which you might include in your code. It returns 0 instead of an error. So, `n = Sheets(3).Range("e13").Value` `If n Then FirstDate = CDate(n)`

Answer (score 1):

In case of Excel 2016 Change your code to

```
Sub mydateaddfunction()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim Number As Integer

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Union(Sheets(1).Range("E13"), Sheets(1).Range("E14"))
    rg.NumberFormat = "[$-fa-IR,16]dd/mm/yyyy;@"


      FirstDate = Sheets(1).Range("e13").Value
      Number = Sheets(1).Range("b13").Value
      Sheets(1).Range("e14").Value = DateAdd("d", Number, FirstDate)
End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest "Does not work " is not really helpful. Anyway, as mentioned, you need to have Excel 2016 Otherwise, you are right, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

By default VBA uses the Gregorian Date Calendar. So I assume that you need to convert your Hijri Date to Gregorian Date and after adding the days to it convert the Gregorian Date back to the Hijri Date.

Please give this a try...

```
Sub mydateaddfunction()
    Dim FirstDate As Date
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim gDate As Date
    FirstDate = HijriToGreg(Sheets(3).Range("e13").Value)
    Number = Sheets(3).Range("b13").Value
    gDate = DateAdd("d", Number, FirstDate)
    Sheets(3).Range("e14").Value = GregToHijri(gDate)
End Sub

Function GregToHijri(dtGegDate As Date) As String
    'Converts Gregorian date to a Hijri date
    VBA.Calendar = vbCalHijri
    GregToHijri = dtGegDate
    VBA.Calendar = vbCalGreg
End Function

Function HijriToGreg(dtHijDate As String) As Date
    'Converts Hijri date to a Gregorian date
    VBA.Calendar = vbCalHijri
    HijriToGreg = dtHijDate
    VBA.Calendar = vbCalGreg
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a simple solution, they can use Excel existing function called "Workday" to add x number of days to a data.

WORKDAY(start_date, days, [holidays])